# How to trigger some action when K8 namespace is deleted

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any default options in kubernetes, to trigger some actions when the resource gets deleted from the cluster?

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/robusta-dev/kubewatch

Answer (score 2):

The default Kubernetes way of doing this is to use an operator.

In a nutshell, you have a software running that is watching resources (`Namespaces` in your case) and react when some namespace changes (deleted in your case).

You might want to add `finalizers` to Namespaces for proper cleanup.

Please refer to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your own service as admission webhook. You can create one that has so-called *side effects*, meaning it does not only interact with the resource in question but may do other things like creating a volume or similar. See the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/.

There are many ways you could implement such a service. For example, with go, you can use the same structs Kubernetes is using itself, which can reduce the development effort. See this package: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/admission/v1. You need to create a small web server that handles a post request, decoding the body into an `AdmissionReview` struct.

There are also third party tools that can do it for you. I havent used it yet, but I think kyverno could fit here: https://kyverno.io/docs/introduction/.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it's worth mentioning that the "callback" function only gets triggered once for admission controllers. If the admission controller backend is down when the Deletion API call is called, then the callback will never be executed. On the other hand, using an operator and a finalizer will ensure the namespace will be "Pending Deleting" until the operator finished the cleanup. But this property might not be important enough to justify the additional burden needed to run an operator.

Comment: @whites11, good point. If you configure this properly, the deletion of the namespace with actually fail if Kubernetes can't get connect to the admission webhook. So you cannot delete unless you got a response from the webhook.